# Rcpp Quicksort error in R?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using RCPP to build a C++ function quicksort for quicksort.
I am trying to compile and load this function through the cxxfunction in R.
I need to use the cxxFunction. I am getting the following message in R:

> error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::IntegerVector {aka Rcpp::Vector<13,
>   Rcpp::PreserveStorage>}'  to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'int
>   quicksort(int*, int, int)' make: *** [file15ecb338ec.o] Error 1

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
incl <- 'int quicksort(int xx[], int left, int right) {

int i = left; 
int j = right;
int tmp;
int pivot = xx[(left + right) / 2];

/* partition */
while (i <= j) {
while (xx[i] < pivot)
i++;
while (xx[j] > pivot)
j--;
if (i <= j) {
tmp = xx[i];
xx[i] = xx[j];
xx[j] = tmp;
i++;
j--;
}
}

/* recursion */
if (left < j){
quicksort(xx, left, j);
}
if (i < right){
quicksort(xx, i, right);
}

return (quicksort(xx,i,j));
}
'
sortCpp <- cxxfunction(signature( x = "integer",left = "integer",
                                  right = "integer"),
                       body = 'IntegerVector arr(x);
                       int a = as<int>(left);
                       int b = as<int>(right);
                       return wrap(quicksort(arr,a,b));',
                       include = incl,
                       plugin = "Rcpp",
                       verbose = TRUE)
```

Just to see if I could call a recursive function using cxxfunction I created a factorial function and called this through cxxfunction and it worked fine.

```
incl <- 'int factorial(int n)
{
  return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
'


factcpp <- cxxfunction(signature( x = "integer"),
                       plugin = "Rcpp",
                       include = incl,
                       body = 'int xnew = as<int>(x);
                       return wrap( factorial(x) );
                       ',
                       verbose = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the compiler says. Your function expects an `int*` but you are passing it an `Rcpp::IntegerVector`. Looking at the [documentation](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/rcpp/0.7.2/class_rcpp_1_1_integer_vector.html) for `Rcpp::IntegerVector`, you can retrieve the raw pointer by `.begin()`, so you would call via `quicksort(arr.begin(), a, b)`.

Also, unless you really need to roll your own quicksort, I would just use the Standard Library's `std::sort`:

```
src <- 'Rcpp::IntegerVector v = Rcpp::IntegerVector(vp);
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
        return wrap(v);'
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(vp="integer"), body=src, plugin="Rcpp")
fun( c(5, 2, 7, -3) )
```

Comment: I amended the line in the cxxfunction to 'return wrap(quicksort(arr.begin(),a,b));' I am now getting a 'error: 'quicksort' was not declared in this scope' error?

Comment: I placed the include before the body parameter in cxxfunction with your amendment and it compiled without errors!. when I ran sortCpp(y) on a vector of integers I got
Error in sortCpp(y) : argument "left" is missing, with no default? Do you know what is the problem here?

Comment: You are not passing in `left` and `right` into `sortCpp`; and you defined `sortCpp` to expect those arguments.

Comment: I am relatively new to r and rcpp and am trying to learn as much as I can. Can you tell me what I need to pass into sortCpp in addition to the vector of unsorted integers y so I can fix and sort this? I thought i needed left and right to be defined as they were arguments in the initial quicksort function.

Comment: When you wrote `quicksort`, you defined a left and right index for the part of the array to sort. I'm not sure if you defined the range to be inclusive [left, right] or half-open [left, right), but in the former case, to sort the entire array you would want to replace the `quicksort(arr.begin(), a, b)` with `quicksort(arr.begin(), 0, arr.size() - 1)` and in the latter case you want `quicksort(arr.begin(), 0, arr.size())`. Or, if you do intend `sortCpp` to sort a particular range in the array, you would call `sortCpp(someVector, left, right)` as you defined.

Comment: I have changed the cxxfunction to  sortCpp <- cxxfunction(signature( x = "integer"), include = incl,
                       body = 'IntegerVector arr(x);
                        return wrap(quicksort(arr.begin(), 0, 
                       arr.size() - 1)
                       quicksort(arr.begin(), 0, arr.size());',
                       plugin = "Rcpp",
                       verbose = TRUE)  I now  get the error error: expected ')' before 'quicksort'?

Comment: The expression is ill-formed as you concatenated my two expressions in a way that doesn't make any sense.. I highly recommend you get a better understanding of C++ first or you will run into a lot of frustration. I'm also 100% sure your quicksort doesn't work as it is recursive on all control paths. It will cause an infinite loop/stack overflow.